# Nifi processor batch insert - handle failure

Tags: java-8, apache-nifi

I am currently in the process of writing an ElasticSearch Nifi processor. Individual inserts / writes to ES are not optimal, instead batching documents is preferred. What would be considered the optimal approach within a Nifi processor to track (batch) documents (FlowFiles) and when at a certain amount batch them in? The part I am most concerned about is if ES is unavailable, down, network partition, etc. prevents the batch from being successful. The primary point of the question, is given that Nifi has content storage for queuing / back-pressure, etc. is there a preferred method for using that to ensure no FlowFiles get lost if a destination is down? Maybe there is another processor I should look at for an example?

I have looked at the Mongo processor, Merge, etc. to try and get an idea of the preferred approach for batching inside of a processor, but can't seem to find anything specific. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Good chance I am overlooking some basic functionality baked into Nifi. I am still fairly new to the platform.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question and a pretty common pattern.  This is why we have the concept of a ProcessSession.  It allows you to send zero or more things to an external endpoint and only commit once you know it has been ack'd by the recipient.  In this sense it offers at least-once semantics.  If the protocol you're using supports two-phase commit style semantics you can get pretty close to the ever elusive exactly-once semantic.  Much of the details of what you're asking about here will depend on the destination systems API and behavior.

There are some examples in the apache codebase which reveal ways to do this.  One way is if you can produce a merged collection of events prior to pushing to the destination system.  Depends on its API.  I think PutMongo and PutSolr operate this way (though the experts on that would need to weigh in).  An example that might be more like what you're looking for can be found in PutSQL which operates on batches of flowfiles to send in a single transaction (on the destination DB).

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/PutSQL.java

Will keep an eye here but can get the eye of a larger NiFi group at users@nifi.apache.org

Thanks
Joe

Comment: Cool. Thanks Joe! I also sent a note to users@nifi.apache.org. I was thinking that if I got an answer there I would re-post here.  I really appreciate your response. I will take a look at the examples.